# How to use a HTML attribute in Razor C#?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I want a way to take the data that I get from data-id attribute and use in in Razor. Is there a way to do that?

```html
<button type="button" name="btnLink" id="btnLink" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalPopUp" data-id="@d.ApplicationId">Attachments</button>
```

I know that in JavaScript I can use something like this:

```js
var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Is there a way to do this in Razor C# in the .cshtml page?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on how you are going to use this

Comment: why you just don't reuse the variable @d.ApplicationId ?

Comment: @Muhammad I want to populate a variable with this data. Like this  int dataId = "the value that I am retrieving must go in this int varaible";